# Cannot able to split the view by two while using mapview. It's showing correctly in preview view

Tags: android, layout, android-mapview

Cannot able to  split the view by two while using mapview. It's showing correctly in preview view.i have tried with relative layout and all. but nothing helps.Maps taked 3/4 of the screen size. i tried invalidate and restart of android studio . i don't know where i made the mistake. any body know, answer me. helps will be appreciated.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/remindermap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/lnrMeetingParticipants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Desc"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Location"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cstmTxtTrackParticipant"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switchRingtone"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/switchRingtone"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:text="Ringtone"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            app:font="@string/robotto_light" />


        <com.kyleduo.switchbutton.SwitchButton
            android:id="@+id/switchRingtone"
            style="@style/SwitchButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            app:kswBackDrawable="@drawable/switch_back_drawable"
            app:kswTextOff="OFF"

            app:kswTextOn="ON"
            app:kswThumbDrawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_drawable"
            app:kswTintColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cstmTxtReminderVibration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switchVibration"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/switchVibration"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Vibration"
            app:font="@string/robotto_light" />


        <com.kyleduo.switchbutton.SwitchButton
            android:id="@+id/switchVibration"
            style="@style/SwitchButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
            app:kswBackDrawable="@drawable/switch_back_drawable"
            app:kswTextOff="OFF"
            app:kswTextOn="ON"
            app:kswThumbDrawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_drawable"
            app:kswTintColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


    </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Now i updated with ImageView. set  visibility to gone on mapview. then added Imageview

```
 <ImageView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:src="@drawable/user"
    />
```

now the view looks like

[image: imageview]

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"` for `MapView` and `LinearLayout` below it.

Comment: no. not working. any other possibilities.posted image. you can check it

Comment: Substitue your `MapView` and `LinearLayout` with ordinary `View`'s with background colors, and see how they behave. The behavior that your describe is weird, it seems to me you are performing some changes runtime (through Java code). Use `Tools->Android->Layout Inspector` too see what's happening in the view hierarchy.

Comment: updated. same behaviour. I dont know where i made the mistake.

Comment: @Ahamed, are you sure you are not changing something from Java code?

Comment: i have just created onCreateview() only. there is nothing than this

Comment: Can you post a simple project demonstrating that behavior?

Comment: this is product. Apologies for that. i convinced with scrollview this time. i will look into later.